# GSheet Arrayformula IF condition equals - need the "equals" to be relative cell reference, not absolute

Tags: google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm building a spreadsheet to crunch survey results.
Here are the colums:

- Col A = Job Title List
- Col B = Typical Tasks List
- Col D = User Job Title
- Col E = User Typical Tasks

When a user inputs their job title in survey, Col D is populated with 'job-title'.
Each new user populates a row.
Col E's job is to find the rows that match their job in Col A, and extract the typical tasks from Col B for those rows.

e.g.:

| User Job Title | User Typical Tasks |
| --- | --- |
| General Manager | Direct organisational operations, projects or services-Provide basic information to guests, visitors, or clients-Direct sales, marketing or customer service activities... |

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz2ub.png)

Here's my forumla:`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(D2:D),,TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$2269=D2,$B$2:$B$2269,""))))`

The problem with this foruma is the =D2 bit. It's stuck referencing D2 for every row, so even though the next user job title is Livestock Farmer, the formula still thinks it's General Manager and extracts the same typical tasks. I need it to update to =D3, =D4,...,=Dn but I don't think I quite have the right type of formula.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(D2:D),1,LAMBDA(r,c,TEXTJOIN("-",1,IFNA(FILTER(B:B,A:A=INDEX(D2:D,r))))))
```